# How to test a page that requires going through other page with Selenium

Tags: selenium

I am new to selenium. It's all setup but I am unable to test some pages.

For example, if I want to test my gmail page where I see all my emails I'd have to go through `gmail.com` then login and only after that could I test it.

How can I make sure the tests only run after having all the information needed to access the page?

For example I want to test https://mail.google.com/mail/#inbox

`await driver.get("https://mail.google.com/mail/#inbox");`

but I need to go through `gmail.com` first.

Comment: Your question is too broad. It should be more specific

Comment: my question is very specific, I want to know how to run the chromedriver in a site that requires more details so as login details for example.

Comment: a first naive try could be to wait once the page is loaded and then check if the url matches the one passed to `driver.get()`

Comment: Better to wait for visibility of some element there

Comment: Question should be like this: I need to perform this, this is my code trials and this is the error I'm getting. How can I resolve it?

Comment: @soundwave not a bad idea, will defintely try that and see if it works

Comment: ok but I'm quite sure Prophet's suggestion is better

Comment: That's all? , I'm happy I could help you without actually giving an answer 